# Is there a magic weapon special ability that gives bludgeoning weapons an improved crit range?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Is there a magic weapon special ability, in Pathfinder, that gives bludgeoning weapons an improved crit range?

I know that in D&D 3.5, there was one called Impact, but in Pathfinder, the Impact weapon special ability is something quite different.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, there is a weapon enhancement that is capable of increasing the crit range of a bludgeoning weapon.

It is a slightly more indirect way, though. As you know, the Improved Critical feat can achieve this effect. And it just so happens that there is a weapon enhancement that gives you a bonus combat feat.

The weapon enhancement I'm talking about is Training, from the Inner Sea Intrigue book. Its price is the equivalent of a +1 bonus, just like Keen.

Here's the full text:

> Price +1 bonus; CL 3rd; Aura faint transmutation
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Popular among those who seek to impersonate skilled warriors, a training weapon grants one combat feat to the wielder as long as the weapon is drawn and in hand. The feat is chosen when this special ability is placed on the weapon. That feat cannot be used as a prerequisite for any other feats and functions for the wielder only if she meets its prerequisites. Once chosen, the feat stored in the weapon cannot be changed.
>
> CONSTRUCTION REQUIREMENTS
>
> Cost +1 bonus Craft Magic Arms and Armor; Spells magic weapon; Special creator must have the chosen combat feat and its prerequisites

The only downside of this method is that you still need to meet the feat's prerequisites, which in this case is proficiency with the weapon and +8 BAB.

The upside however is that if you are dual-wielding identical weapons, only one of them needs to have the enhancement.

Comment: @J.Puckett This is a great answer! If you think that it [solves your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the check mark icon next to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### No, there is no magic weapon special ability that increases the critical threat range specifically for bludgeoning weapons.

Among the PFSRD's [list of magic weapon special abilities](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/), only the [*keen*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/keen/) ability can increase a weapon's threat range. It can only be added to melee weapons that deal piercing or slashing damage.

> This ability doubles the threat range of a weapon. Only piercing or slashing melee weapons can be keen. If you roll this special ability randomly for an inappropriate weapon, reroll. This benefit doesn’t stack with any other effects that expand the threat range of a weapon (such as the keen edge spell or the Improved Critical feat).

By default, bludgeoning weapons do not qualify for the *keen* ability.

However, a bludgeoning weapon can be *keen* if it also deals piercing or slashing damage. A [morningstar](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/morningstar/)'s damage type is B and P (both bludgeoning and piercing), thus a +1 *keen* morningstar would be valid. Similarly, if a creature has [bite or claw natural weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Natural_Attacks), then a *keen* [Amulet of Mighty Fists](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists/) would expand the threat ranges of their bite (B, P, and S) and claw (B and S) attacks.

Comment: Ok thanks. The other option is improved critical.

Comment: @J.Puckett [Improved Critical](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-critical-combat/) is a feat. Your question asked about magic weapon special abilities. Were you looking for other ways to increase a bludgeoning weapon's threat range?

Comment: Yes I was, but it didn't seem like there was.  Thanks